# Enable/disable a BoxCollider via script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My player has an weapon in his hand, which swings on attack and deals damage when it hits the enemy. But i want the collider to be able only when the player is attacking, when pressing F for example. What i have  >

```
GameObject weapon = transform.FindChild("orc_weapon").gameObject; 

if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
            weapon.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().enabled = false;
```

For some reason this destroy my player gameobject.... i also tried getting the weapon with       GameObject weapon = GameObject.Find("orc_weapon");  In this case, when i press F i get the unassigned exception weapon has not been assineged, i Debuged it and it prints orc_weapon

Comment: Regarding `transform.FindChild("orc_weapon").gameObject;`, is the `orc_weapon` definitely a child of the object this script is attached to?

Comment: try assigning the PolygonCollider in the inspector...
public PolygonCollider2D weaponCollider;
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F))
weaponCollider.enabled = false;

Comment: I think we'll need some more information to solve this, how's you setup? How's your gameObject hierarchy build up?

Answer (score 0):

Guys there where 2 gameobjects with the name orc_weapon! that was the problem! i changed the name to player_weapon and it works now =D thanks anyway!